# Stopping control of oscillating converging error

Tags: equation-solving, error-tracking

I am doing many simulations of nonlinear differential equations. The differential equations are of the form

$$y''(t)+g\left(y(t),y'(t)\right)=p \cos (2 \pi  f t)$$

The solution settles to a periodic function. My problem is how to stop the simulation when the solution has become approximately periodic. How can I tell it has converged to a known accuracy?

The function g can be complicated but as a minimum working example I set up a simple system as follows. I use `WhenEvent` to identify the maxima and then look at the difference between neighbouring maxima.
I then give an example of a simulation and plot the time history, the maxima and the differences.

```
ClearAll[g, sim];
g[y_, v_] := 398.  y + 5000  y^3 + 1.257  v

sim[{y0_, v0_}, f_, p_, nn_] := Module[{oldY, sol, y, v},
  oldY = y0;
  sol = Reap[{y, v} /. First@NDSolve[{
        y'[t] == v[t],
        v'[t] + g[y[t], v[t]] == p  Cos[2 \[Pi]  f  t],
        WhenEvent[
         v[t] == 0 && y[t] > 0,
         Sow[{t, y[t], v[t], y[t] - oldY}];
         oldY = y[t]
         ],
        y[0] == y0, v[0] == v0},
       {y, v}, {t, 0, nn/f}]]
  ]

res = sim[{0.8, 0}, 8, 80., 100];
Plot[res[[1, 1]][t], {t, 0, 100/11}, PlotRange -> All]
ListPlot[res[[2, 1, All, {1, 2}]], PlotRange -> All]
ListLogPlot[Abs[res[[2, 1, All, {1, 4}]]], PlotRange -> All, 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the last plot the differences do suggest that the system is converging. However, if for example, I set the stopping control for when the difference is 10^-5 the simulation would stop at about 8 seconds but the overall error is still about 10^-3 two orders of magnitude less then my target. There are high points and low points in the differences. I don't know where the high points occur.

What is a good test for stopping control that will give me a known accuracy?

Thanks

Comment: Please, add `t` to $p \cos (2 \pi f t)$ in latex code.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Error corrected. Thanks

Comment: @Goofy If you look at the last plot. This shows the differences of the errors. Here you can see a difference at  the y-value of  10^-5 which has an x-value of about 8. Thanks for looking at this. Perhaps I need to make this clearer.

Comment: So the problem is the difference between the high and low points between, say, x=8 and x=8.5? The low point meets the stopping criterion of <10^-5 and the following high point shows an error of around 10^-3 — that's what you're referring to?

Comment: @Goofy Yes that's the problem. I can't predict where the high points will be. The high points are the ones I should use as the stopping criterion.

Comment: Would this work?: `ncycles = 5;
dy = ConstantArray[1., ncycles];`, where `ncycles` is the number of cycles to keep, and update in the `WhenEvent` with
`dy = Prepend[Most@dy, y[t] - oldY]`. Then one can use `Max[Abs[dy]]` for the stopping criterion. The initialization to all 1s is meant to keep `NDSolve` from stopping until at least the number of cycles that have been computed exceeds `ncycles`. You might want `ncycles` to be larger, if you're worried that a peak does not occur every 5 cycles.

Comment: @Goofy That's in the correct direction. However, I don't know the length of the list of previous values to keep. Some sort of exponential smoothing of previous values would also work but I don' know  a scale of how far back to go.  Perhaps keep a track of previous big and small values...